# PopupMenu equivalent in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

What is the [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) equivalent in ActionBarSherlock? I can't seem to find it. Its API 11, why is it absent?

Comment: AFAIK, `PopupMenu` is not required for an action bar. ActionBarSherlock isn't a backport of *everything*.

Comment: Also, I see at least one (non-general-purpose) [backport of `PopupMenu`](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/shoppinglist/ShoppingList/src/org/openintents/shopping/ui/widget/backport/PopupMenu.java?r=3810) in the first page of a Google search for `android popupmenu backport`, so you might consider just grabbing the AOSP source and trying to backport it yourself.

Answer (score 11):

The Class [MenuPopupHelper](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/view/menu/MenuPopupHelper.java) pretty much does the job. I didn't find an easy way to listen for Item Clicks though, so I implemented this class that derives from MenuPopupHelper:

```
public class MenuPopup extends MenuPopupHelper {

    OnMenuItemClickListener onMenuItemClickListener;

    public MenuPopup(Context context, MenuBuilder menu, View anchorView) {
        super(context, menu, anchorView);
    }

    public void setOnMenuItemClickListener(
            OnMenuItemClickListener onMenuItemClickListener) {
        this.onMenuItemClickListener = onMenuItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        super.onItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        if (onMenuItemClickListener != null)
            onMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(position);
    }

    public interface OnMenuItemClickListener{
        public void onMenuItemClick(int itemID);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not perfect as the anchorView view object must implement View_OnAttachStateChangeListener interface that required by AcctionBarSherlock.

Comment: It's quite easy to make a `View` implementing the `View_HasStateListenerSupport` interface. You can find a example of implementation here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java

Answer (score 3):

Added `PopupMenu` in [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/mihirjoshi21/ActionBarSherlock).

Styling of the `PopupMenu` -

```
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.MyAppTheme</item>      

<style name="PopupMenu.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on this currently.  I did what was suggested by CommonsWare about backporting it.  I basically took the PopupMenu.java source code and replaced the package imports with the actionbarsherlock equivalents.  It seems to work fine on the gingerbread and ics devices I tested on. The catch though is in actionbarsherlocks MenuPopupHelper class I had to comment lines referencing View_HasStateListenerSupport like:

```
((View_HasStateListenerSupport)anchor).addOnAttachStateChangeListener(this);
```

for some reason. If I didn't I would get a ClassCastException:

> E/AndroidRuntime(9197): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9197): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.View_HasStateListenerSupport
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9197):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:121)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(9197):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:102)

I'm unsure if commenting out that listener could cause problems for other classes that utilize MenuPopupHelper or why they are causing this exception (maybe a bug). But I thought I would share what I tried, so it may help anyone looking into this.